# How to make a lightspeed scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting, motion-blur

I am trying to create a lightspeed scene just like this.[image]

I have tried using particle systems with motion blur, but i could never get it to look right. Let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Did you want this as an animation, starting from a star (dot) to the long streak? or will this be a still image?

Comment: I will want this to be an animation starting from a star to a long streak

Answer (score 6):

**SOLUTION 1 POST PRO - Compositor/Directional blur**

I started with a cube filled with static particles, all using an icosphere as the rendered object. Then I set up a Directional Blur node to animate the streak from the rendered image.

[image: Streaks directional blur node]

I also added some glare nodes to enhance the streaks as they get a bit transparent when distorted. I would render any spaceship interior on another layer so i could separate the zoom effect.

**SOLUTION 2 POST PRO - Compositor/vector blur**

You can use Vector Blur in the compositor.
I have made a larger volume of stars with an array of the initial cube. Then I fly the camera quite fast through it.
In the compositor I use a Vector node with a high number of samples (256).
In this way I can animate the streaks by moving the camera.

[image: Streaks vector node]

**SOLUTION 3 POST PRO - In camera/Compositor**

[image: camera in volume]

Use the moving camera again but this time turn on the actual motion blur feature in Cycles on the scene properties panel.
To emphasize the streak I have animated the size of the particle object (icosphere) as the camera speeds up.

[image: animate particle object]

I have added a second layer to render the cockpit image, which is parented to the camera location.

[image: Layers for streaks]

I used the compositor to place the cockpit over the star image. I found that if the cockpit object was in the star layer, the particles would streak inside the cabin. Notice that the cockpit layer only has an object with an Emission material so i have turned the sample rate down to 1. This renders very fast.

[image: composite star streaks]

**SOLUTION 4 POST PRO - In camera/Particle hair**

[image: Star Streaks animated with hair]

In this example I have used particle hair and animated the length via the Path end value. At the same time I am animating the position of the camera (with cockpit object).

[image: animated path length]

Here you can see the array of planes with a hole in the middle for the camera to fly down.

[image: Array plane for particles]

In this frame is the rendered view and the display view showing the hair increasing in length.

[image: particle length side view]

---

Comment: Nice - for what purpose are the holes in the planes? Are they necessary?

Comment: I found that if I used a plane or a cube with random particles, the particles would occasionally end up inside the cabin. To stop that happening I decided to fly the camera and cabin through a hole that doesn't have any particles.

Comment: Aha - of course. That makes sense - thanks for the explanation.